# Why does Skype obsolete so many Java packages and how can I have both?

Tags: apt, package-management, java, skype

```
$ apt install skype
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
The following packages were automatically installed and are no longer required:
  gir1.2-langtag-0.5 glassfish-javaee gperf groovy groovy-doc groovy2 gstreamer1.0-doc ivy ivy-doc libabw-dev libaether-java
  libaopalliance-java libaopalliance-java-doc libasync-http-client-java libasync-http-client-java-doc libaxis-java
  libaxis-java-doc libbcpg-java libbcpg-java-doc libbluetooth-dev libboost-date-time-dev libcastor-core-java libcastor-java-doc
  libcastor-xml-java libcdi-api-java libcdr-dev libclassworlds-java libclassworlds-java-doc libclucene-dev libcmis-dev
  libcommons-configuration-java libcommons-configuration-java-doc libcommons-discovery-java libcommons-discovery-java-doc
  libcommons-fileupload-java libcommons-jexl2-java libcommons-jexl2-java-doc libcommons-jxpath-java libcommons-jxpath-java-doc
  libcommons-lang3-java libcommons-lang3-java-doc libcommons-net2-java libcommons-net2-java-doc libcommons-validator-java
  libcommons-vfs-java libcommons-vfs-java-doc libcppunit-1.13-0v5 libcppunit-dev libcppunit-doc libcups2-dev libdoxia-core-java
  libdoxia-java libdoxia-java-doc libdoxia-sitetools-java libdoxia-sitetools-java-doc libdrm-dev:i386 libe-book-dev libeot-dev
  libetonyek-dev libexttextcat-dev libfreehand-dev libgeronimo-ejb-3.0-spec-java libgeronimo-interceptor-3.0-spec-java
  libgeronimo-jms-1.1-spec-java libgeronimo-validation-1.0-spec-java libgeronimo-validation-1.0-spec-java-doc libgl1-mesa-dev:i386
  libglew-dev libglm-dev libgpars-groovy-java libgpars-groovy-java-doc libgraphite2-dev libgssrpc4:i386
  libgstreamer-plugins-base1.0-dev libgstreamer1.0-dev libhessian-java libhessian-java-doc libhttpclient-java libhttpcore-java
  libhunspell-dev libhyphen-dev libisorelax-java libitext1-java libixion-0.10-0v5 libjackson-json-java libjackson-json-java-doc
  libjamon-java libjboss-vfs-java libjcsp-java libjcsp-java-doc libjdependency-java libjdom2-java libjdom2-java-doc
  libjettison-java libjibx-java libjibx1.1-java-doc libjibx1.2-java libjline2-java libjsoup-java libjsoup-java-doc
  libjsr311-api-java libjsr311-api-java-doc libkadm5clnt-mit9:i386 libkadm5srv-mit9:i386 libkdb5-8:i386
  libknopflerfish-osgi-framework-java libknopflerfish-osgi-java-doc liblangtag-dev liblangtag-doc liblangtag-gobject0
  liblpsolve55-dev libmaven-archiver-java libmaven-archiver-java-doc libmaven-clean-plugin-java libmaven-clean-plugin-java-doc
  libmaven-common-artifact-filters-java libmaven-common-artifact-filters-java-doc libmaven-compiler-plugin-2.5-java
  libmaven-compiler-plugin-2.5-java-doc libmaven-dependency-tree-java libmaven-dependency-tree-java-doc libmaven-doxia-tools-java
  libmaven-doxia-tools-java-doc libmaven-filtering-java libmaven-install-plugin-java libmaven-install-plugin-java-doc
  libmaven-invoker-java libmaven-jar-plugin-java libmaven-jar-plugin-java-doc libmaven-javadoc-plugin-java
  libmaven-plugin-tools-java libmaven-reporting-impl-java libmaven-reporting-impl-java-doc libmaven-resources-plugin-java
  libmaven-resources-plugin-java-doc libmaven-shade-plugin-java libmaven-shade-plugin-java-doc libmaven-shared-utils-java
  libmaven-shared-utils-java-doc libmaven-site-plugin-java libmaven-site-plugin-java-doc libmaven2-core-java
  libmaven2-core-java-doc libmdds-dev libmockobjects-java libmspub-dev libmsv-java libmwaw-dev libmysqlcppconn-dev
  libneon27-gnutls-dev libnetty-3.9-java libnspr4-dev libnss3-dev libodfgen-dev liborcus-dev liborcus-spreadsheet-model-0.10-0v5
  libpagemaker-dev libplexus-ant-factory-java libplexus-archiver-java libplexus-bsh-factory-java libplexus-build-api-java
  libplexus-build-api-java-doc libplexus-cipher-java libplexus-cipher-java-doc libplexus-classworlds-java
  libplexus-classworlds-java-doc libplexus-classworlds2-java libplexus-classworlds2-java-doc libplexus-cli-java
  libplexus-cli-java-doc libplexus-compiler-1.0-java libplexus-compiler-1.0-java-doc libplexus-container-default-java
  libplexus-container-default-java-doc libplexus-containers-java libplexus-containers-java-doc libplexus-containers1.5-java
  libplexus-i18n-java libplexus-i18n-java-doc libplexus-interactivity-api-java libplexus-interactivity-api-java-doc
  libplexus-interpolation-java libplexus-interpolation-java-doc libplexus-io-java libplexus-sec-dispatcher-java
  libplexus-sec-dispatcher-java-doc libplexus-utils-java libplexus-utils-java-doc libplexus-utils2-java libplexus-utils2-java-doc
  libplexus-velocity-java libplexus-velocity-java-doc libpoppler-cpp-dev libpoppler-cpp0 libpoppler-dev libpoppler-private-dev
  libpthread-stubs0-dev:i386 libqdox-java libqdox-java-doc libraptor2-dev libraptor2-doc librasqal3-dev librasqal3-doc librdf0-dev
  librelaxng-datatype-java librevenge-dev libservlet3.1-java libsisu-guice-java libsisu-ioc-java libspring-aop-java
  libspring-beans-java libspring-context-java libspring-core-java libspring-expression-java libspring-instrument-java
  libspring-oxm-java libspring-web-java libssl-dev:i386 libstax-java libstax-java-doc libstax2-api-java libsuitesparse-dev
  libsurefire-java libtomcat8-java libvigraimpex-dev libvigraimpex-doc libvigraimpex5v5 libvisio-dev libwagon-java
  libwagon-java-doc libwerken.xpath-java libwoodstox-java libwpd-dev libwpg-dev libwps-dev libwsdl4j-java libx11-dev:i386
  libx11-xcb-dev:i386 libxau-dev:i386 libxbean-java libxcb-dri2-0-dev:i386 libxcb-dri3-dev:i386 libxcb-glx0-dev:i386
  libxcb-present-dev:i386 libxcb-randr0:i386 libxcb-randr0-dev:i386 libxcb-render0:i386 libxcb-render0-dev:i386 libxcb-shape0:i386
  libxcb-shape0-dev:i386 libxcb-sync-dev:i386 libxcb-xfixes0:i386 libxcb-xfixes0-dev:i386 libxcb1-dev:i386 libxdamage-dev:i386
  libxdmcp-dev:i386 libxext-dev:i386 libxfixes-dev:i386 libxmlbeans-java libxshmfence-dev:i386 libxstream-java libxxf86vm-dev:i386
  maven-debian-helper maven-repo-helper maven2 mesa-common-dev:i386 python-h5py python-librdf python-vigra python-vigra-doc
  velocity velocity-doc
Use 'apt-get autoremove' to remove them.
The following extra packages will be installed:
  firebird-dev:i386 firebird2.5-server-common:i386 gstreamer1.0-plugins-base:i386 gstreamer1.0-tools:i386 libaudio2:i386
  libc6-dev:i386 libcap2:i386 libdatrie1:i386 libdbusmenu-qt2:i386 libfbclient2:i386 libfbembed2.5:i386
  libgstreamer-plugins-base1.0-0:i386 libgstreamer1.0-0:i386 libib-util:i386 libltdl-dev:i386 libmng2:i386 libmysqlclient-dev:i386
  libqt4-dbus:i386 libqt4-declarative:i386 libqt4-declarative-folderlistmodel:i386 libqt4-declarative-gestures:i386
  libqt4-declarative-particles:i386 libqt4-declarative-shaders:i386 libqt4-designer:i386 libqt4-dev:i386 libqt4-help:i386
  libqt4-network:i386 libqt4-opengl:i386 libqt4-qt3support:i386 libqt4-script:i386 libqt4-scripttools:i386 libqt4-sql:i386
  libqt4-sql-sqlite:i386 libqt4-svg:i386 libqt4-test:i386 libqt4-xml:i386 libqt4-xmlpatterns:i386 libqtcore4:i386 libqtdbus4:i386
  libqtgui4:i386 libqtwebkit-dev:i386 libqtwebkit4:i386 libsqlite3-dev:i386 libthai0:i386 libxss1:i386 libxtst6:i386 libxv1:i386
  linux-libc-dev:i386 nas:i386 odbcinst1debian2:i386 qt4-designer:i386 qt4-dev-tools:i386 qt4-qmlviewer:i386 qt4-qtconfig:i386
  skype-bin:i386 sni-qt:i386 unixodbc-dev:i386 zlib1g-dev:i386
Suggested packages:
  firebird2.5-examples:i386 manpages-dev:i386 libtool-doc:i386 libpq-dev:i386 libsqlite0-dev:i386 qt4-doc:i386 libicu52:i386
  sqlite3-doc:i386 audiooss:i386 qt4-doc-html:i386
Recommended packages:
  libqt4-opengl-dev:i386
The following packages will be REMOVED:
  automoc firebird-dev firebird2.5-server-common kdelibs5-dev libfbembed2.5 libkrb5-dev libmysqlclient-dev libphonon-dev libpq-dev
  libqt4-dev libqt4-opengl-dev libqtwebkit-dev libreoffice-subsequentcheckbase libsqlite0-dev python-sqlite-dbg qt4-designer
  qt4-dev-tools unixodbc-dev
The following NEW packages will be installed:
  firebird-dev:i386 firebird2.5-server-common:i386 gstreamer1.0-plugins-base:i386 gstreamer1.0-tools:i386 libaudio2:i386
  libc6-dev:i386 libcap2:i386 libdatrie1:i386 libdbusmenu-qt2:i386 libfbclient2:i386 libfbembed2.5:i386
  libgstreamer-plugins-base1.0-0:i386 libgstreamer1.0-0:i386 libib-util:i386 libltdl-dev:i386 libmng2:i386 libmysqlclient-dev:i386
  libqt4-dbus:i386 libqt4-declarative:i386 libqt4-declarative-folderlistmodel:i386 libqt4-declarative-gestures:i386
  libqt4-declarative-particles:i386 libqt4-declarative-shaders:i386 libqt4-designer:i386 libqt4-dev:i386 libqt4-help:i386
  libqt4-network:i386 libqt4-opengl:i386 libqt4-qt3support:i386 libqt4-script:i386 libqt4-scripttools:i386 libqt4-sql:i386
  libqt4-sql-sqlite:i386 libqt4-svg:i386 libqt4-test:i386 libqt4-xml:i386 libqt4-xmlpatterns:i386 libqtcore4:i386 libqtdbus4:i386
  libqtgui4:i386 libqtwebkit-dev:i386 libqtwebkit4:i386 libsqlite3-dev:i386 libthai0:i386 libxss1:i386 libxtst6:i386 libxv1:i386
  linux-libc-dev:i386 nas:i386 odbcinst1debian2:i386 qt4-designer:i386 qt4-dev-tools:i386 qt4-qmlviewer:i386 qt4-qtconfig:i386
  skype skype-bin:i386 sni-qt:i386 unixodbc-dev:i386 zlib1g-dev:i386
0 upgraded, 59 newly installed, 18 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
Need to get 61.3 MB of archives.
After this operation, 146 MB of additional disk space will be used.
```

`apt-get autoremove` gives no output, which means the `The following packages were automatically installed and are no longer required` is because of Skype.

Why does package `skype` obsolete so many (probably important!) Java-related packages, and can I have both at once? This is Ubuntu 15.10.

`apt-get purge skype` gives `Package 'skype' is not installed, so not removed`.

Installing *other* packages gives, for instance,

```
The following extra packages will be installed:
  libfinance-yahooquote-perl
The following NEW packages will be installed:
  libfinance-yahooquote-perl smtm
0 upgraded, 2 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
```

So it's Skype-specific.

---

It was recommended in the comments that I remove each of the "the following packages will be REMOVED" one by one to see which give the long list of removals, and I did that like:

```
A=$(for i in `echo automoc firebird-dev firebird2.5-server-common kdelibs5-dev libfbembed2.5 libkrb5-dev libmysqlclient-dev libphonon-dev libpq-dev libqt4-dev libqt4-opengl-dev libqtwebkit-dev libreoffice-subsequentcheckbase libsqlite0-dev python-sqlite-dbg qt4-designer qt4-dev-tools unixodbc-dev`
    do echo; echo PACKAGE IS $i IS PACKAGE
    echo; echo -e '\04' | apt remove $i; done
) 
printf "$A" > a
```

I've ended up with the following list:

```
automoc 
kdelibs5-dev 
libmysqlclient-dev 
libphonon-dev 
libpq-dev 
libqt4-dev 
libreoffice-subsequentcheckbase 
unixodbc-dev
```

So now the question is more like, why do those packages need to be removed by Skype and why do they cause the long list of obsoletions?

Comment: what  'apt-get purge skype*'  does?

Comment: @Ashu I've edited my question

Comment: something is wrong with your command. "apt install skype" should throw an error regarding the lock file and not a list of packages. I would assume it is "sudo apt-get install skype"?

Comment: @Rinzwind `apt` is `alias`ed to `apt-get install`, sorry

Comment: I'm not convinced that the list of "no longer required" packages is related to the skype installation. What's the answer if you run `sudo apt-get upgrade`?

Comment: @GunnarHjalmarsson I tried that, it just gives `0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.`

Comment: An idea: What if you run `sudo dpkg --add-architecture i386 && sudo apt-get update` and then try to install skype?

Comment: @GunnarHjalmarsson nope, same thing

Comment: Can you find which specific package that "will be REMOVED" triggers the "no longer required" notice when you try to remove it? Try doing `sudo apt-get remove` on each of those packages one by one.

Comment: @DamianYerrick I've edited my question

Comment: Any takers for a bet on libqt4 being the problem package? Skype uses Qt.

Comment: @muru If Skype needs Qt, then why does it want to remove it?

Comment: It might be looking for a particular version, or a dependency might have a conflict with the version of Qt you do have.

Comment: @muru solution was simpler than I thought.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up going ahead and removing the long list of packages, and then reinstalling them all, which works perfectly.